# SQL Server - Join between a table and a Where IN query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

Table_A

```
--------------------
Column_1 | Column_2
--------------------
10001    | 0.4
10002    | 0.5
```

Can I have the following output without creating a temporary table or firing two different queries

```
Select Column_1, Column_2 
from Table_A 
where Column_1 in (10001, 10002, 10003)
```

as following output

```
--------------------
Column_1 | Column_2
--------------------
10001    | 0.4
10002    | 0.5
10003    | null
```

Comment: You state you have two tables, but only included one. Where does 10003 come from? Is it hard-coded?

Comment: MySql is not Sql Server. Please don't tag irrelevant products.

Comment: Whatever values you want to search, store those values in a temp table or a table variable and then use left join.

Comment: Murelink, have modified the query, my bad. There is a single table, and I wanted to get it in the output form. I have accepted the answer that worked perfectly for my given problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` & `Table valued constructor`

```
SELECT Tc.Column_1,
       A.Column_2
FROM   (VALUES(10001),
              (10002),
              (10003)) tc(Column_1)
       LEFT JOIN Table_A a
              ON tc.Column_1 = A.Column_1
```

If you are using Mysql

```
SELECT Tc.Column_1,
       A.Column_2
FROM   (SELECT 10001 Column_1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 10002
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 10003) tc
       LEFT JOIN Table_A a
              ON tc.Column_1 = A.Column_1
```

You may have to change input format from your current approach

Comment: Perfect the first query worked for SQL Server. I don't know why my question was down voted, as I had worked hard to get a solution in a single query without using loops or temporary table. This one is quiet cool.

Comment: @AmitPandey - Downvote could be for two reasons. 1. You didn't show your effort to solve the problem(query). 2. Tagging irrelevant database engines. When you are using `Sql Server` do not tag `Mysql` both are very different database engines.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you consider an inline view a temp table; I don't.

SQL can't create data it can only select data that exists.  That being said we can create an inline view with the desired data and then select from it.

```
SELECT tmp.Col1, A.Column_2 
FROM (SELECT 10001 as col1 union all 
      SELECT 10002 union all 
      SELECT 10003) tmp
LEFT JOIN Table_A  A
 on tmp.col1 = A.Column_1
```